Plotting shift in observed wavelength with redshift/lookback time
I'm looking for a graphic that clearly shows the shifting of wavelengths with redshift/lookback time. I've produced the following:

The plot is intended to show that, for example, for a source at a redshift of $z=4$, the $z$ line ($\lambda_\text{rest}=9.134\times10^{-7}$ m) has been shifted to the wavelength of the $W2$ line ($\lambda_\text{rest}=4.65\times10^{-7}$ m), but I don't think it's very intuitive.
Is there a better way to show this?

This may get closed as Q's of intuitiveness are often option-based but these are mine: It's not wrong but nanometers or microns, rather than meters, are likely to be more intuitive for the optical/infra-red part of the spectrum. Other than that, maybe have the color of the line change along the line with changing redshift/wavelength or add a partially transparent rainbow in the background over the appropriate range of wavelengths ?
